# Custom database tables for Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to create custom tables for Identity Authentication, but I keep getting this error no matter how many times I have tried to recreate the Identity tables:

> The entity types 'BBRoleType' and 'UserRoleType' cannot share table 'UserRoleTypes' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

This is my User tables in the database:

[image: User tables]

And exported as SQL:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 21/12/2015 18:42:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [IsConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastOnlineDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [BirthDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FacebookAccessToken] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [FacebookName] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [FacebookId] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserClaim]    Script Date: 21/12/2015 18:42:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserClaim](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ClaimValue] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserClaim] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserLogin]    Script Date: 21/12/2015 18:42:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLogin](
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [UserLoginId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserLogin] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserLoginId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserRole]    Script Date: 21/12/2015 18:42:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRole](
    [RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserRoleType]    Script Date: 21/12/2015 18:42:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRoleType](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserRoleType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_User_IsConfirmed]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsConfirmed]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserLogin] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UserLogin_UserLoginId]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [UserLoginId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserRoleType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UserRoleType_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserClaim]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserClaim_User] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserClaim] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserClaim_User]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserLogin]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserLogin_User] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserLogin] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserLogin_User]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserRole]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRole_User] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserRole] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRole_User]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserRole]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRole_UserRoleTyp] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UserRoleType] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserRole] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRole_UserRoleTyp]
GO
```

After creating the table, I have added a ADO.NET Data Entity Model for the database.

I have created these classes to map to the custom Identity classes:

```
public class BBUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid> { }
public class BBUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }

public class BBRoleType : IdentityRole<Guid,BBUserRole> { }
public class BBUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid> { }

public class BBUser : IdentityUser<Guid, BBUserLogin, BBUserRole, BBUserClaim>
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastOnlineDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string FacebookAccessToken { get; set; }
    public string FacebookName { get; set; }
    public string FacebookId { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<BBUser, Guid> manager)
    { 
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(TCCustomClaimTypes.FirstName, this.FacebookName.SubstringUpToFirst(' ')));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

And then setup my DbContext as this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<BBUser, BBRoleType, Guid, BBUserLogin, BBUserRole, BBUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MyIdentityConnection")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");

        modelBuilder.Entity<BBUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<BBUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<BBUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<BBUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<BBRoleType>().ToTable("UserRoleType");

        modelBuilder.Entity<BBUser>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BBUserClaim>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BBRoleType>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
```

Not that I think i matters, but I am using `Guid`/`[uniqueidentifier]` as Ids where I can (the places where the generic `TKey` is used). The `IdentityUserClaim` does not allow to change the Id-type, so I am using a `bigint` for that. Not that I think it matters :-)

I have been banging my head against the wall the entire day with this problem, but I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the key names Id, Id, UserId, and RoleId need to have proper naming.  Can you change the key 'Id' to 'UserId' on the 'User' table?  Drop the Id key on UserClaim table.  Change 'Id' on UserRoleType table to RoleId.

I think that will fix your issue.

Comment: But the Id names should be the right ones. The User-table has to match the `IdentityUser` class, which dictates a `public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }` property, which is why I have used the name `Id`. If there is a way to work around it, I am happy to hear it.

Comment: I dont think the issue is with the code, though it would need to be modified, but the issue lies at the database, your model doesnt have proper relationship keying.  For instance,  your User table has a key of Id, then you have another table that has UserId as the key, which supposedly would map back to User.Id  but thats nasty.  Make the keys properly named the same.  You could use Id in the right places for the userId, so drop userId as a key and dont use 'Id' as a key for anything else other than user.

Comment: I don't understand if Entity Framework would create references for ids automatically just because of the name being `Id` or `UserId`. I have exported the database as SQL to show how the keys are setup (updated the question).